# For which Noetherian local rings, is every associated prime ideal contained in the square of the maximal ideal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-rings, primary-decomposition

Let $(R,\mathfrak m, k)$ be a Noetherian local ring of depth $>1$. If $a\in R$ is a zero-divisor, i.e. if $ab=0$ for some $0\ne b \in R$, then must it be true that $a\in \mathfrak m^2$? Since the collection of all zero divisors is the union of all associated primes, so in other words I'm asking: Is it true that every associated prime is inside $\mathfrak m^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $R=k[[x,y,z]]/xy$. It has depth two, $xy=0$, but $x$ is not in the square of the maximal ideal.

Answer (score 0):

While the general statement is false, it is true that for **regular local rings** (i.e. $\dim R = \dim_k \frak{m}/\frak{m}^2$), every zerodivisor (and hence associated prime) is contained in $\frak{m}^2$.
(The following argument is inspired by Exercise 12.1.B and 12.2.B of Vakil's [THE RISING SEA
Foundations of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf).)

**Proof.**
If $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ is regular and $a\in \mathfrak{m}$, then we see that
$$
\dim_k \frac{\mathfrak{m}/(a)}{(\mathfrak{m}/(a))^2}
=
\dim_k \frac{\frak{m}}{(a)+\frak{m}^2}
=
\begin{cases}
\dim_k \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 &\text{if $a\in \mathfrak{m}^2$}\\
\dim_k \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 - 1 &\text{if $a\in \frak{m}\setminus\frak{m}^2$}
\end{cases}
$$
On the other hand, by Corollary 11.18 in Atiyah-Macdonald's *Commutative algebra*,
$$
\dim R/(a) = 
\begin{cases}
\dim R &\text{if $a$ is a zerodivisor}\\
\dim R - 1 &\text{if $a$ is not a zerodivisor}
\end{cases}
$$
We can now prove the contrapositive: if $a\in \frak{m}\setminus \frak{m}^2$, then by regularity
$$
\dim R - 1 \leq \dim R/(a) \leq \dim_k \frac{\mathfrak{m}/(a)}{(\mathfrak{m}/(a))^2} = \dim_k \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 - 1 = \dim R -1, $$
whence $\dim R/(a) = \dim R - 1$ and $a$ is not a zerodivisor.
Q.E.D.

Comment: A regular local ring is a domain, so the statement is vacuous, since there are no zero divisors in R; the only associated prime of $R$ is $0$.

Comment: @metalspringpro Oops, thanks for pointing it out. I didn't know it before.